# Rendering error occured when adding ToggleButton in Android API 10

Tags: android, android-layout, togglebutton

As far as I know `ToggleButton` was added in API 1 and I chose `API 10` as my minimum sdk in my app. I added `ToggleButton` in my `activity.xml` but it doesn't work.

I already tried restarting my IDE but no good.
It keeps returning this error.

```
Rendering Problems
The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:

    - Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect. (Ignore for this session)
    - Path.isConvex is not supported. (Ignore for this session)

Ignore all fidelity warnings for this session.

Exception raised during rendering: -1
```

Here is my `ToggleButton` code in my `activity.xml`:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent" />
```